# oracle query return duplicate data

Tags: sql, oracle, ado.net

I have written a oracle query to fetch data and it's return duplicate data,So that i use **distinct** keyword.But I get an error:- **ORA-01791: not a SELECTed** expression

Oracle Query:-

```
  Select Distinct  pi.first_name || ' ' || pi.last_name initiator
                 , pi.user_id
                 , c.country_name
                 , e.eform_name
                 , w.date_stamp_utc
                 , decode (
                           waRating.attr_value, 4, 'Very Positive',
                                                3, 'Positive',
                                                2, 'Neutral',
                                                1, 'Negative',
                                                0, 'Very Negative', '???'
                          ) rating
                , waEnv.attr_value environment
                , nvl(ua.agent_name, '???') browser
                , nvl(ua.agent_version, '???') version
                , waFeedback.attr_value negative_feedback

            From request_workflow w 
      Inner Join request_workflow_attribute waRating
              On waRating.request_workflow_id = w.row_id
             And waRating.attr_name = 'UserRating'
      Inner Join request_workflow_attribute waEnv
              On waEnv.request_workflow_id = w.row_id
             And waEnv.attr_name = 'Environment'
      Inner Join request_workflow_attribute waBrowser
              On waBrowser.request_workflow_id = w.row_id
             And waBrowser.attr_name = 'UserAgent'
       Left Join request_workflow_attribute waFeedback
              On waFeedback.request_workflow_id = w.row_id
             And waFeedback.attr_name = 'UserFeedback'
      Inner Join person_info pi
              On w.performer_id = pi.row_id
      Inner Join request_common rc
              On w.request_id = rc.row_id
      Inner Join eform e
              On rc.eform_id = e.row_id
       Left Join user_agent ua
              On waBrowser.attr_value = ua.user_agent_raw
      Inner Join country c
              On pi.country_code = c.country_code

           Where w.date_stamp_utc 
         Between '1-dec-2014' And '31-dec-2015'
        Order By waRating.attr_value desc, eform_name;
```

Please suggest how to make it work.

Comment: First of all, this is not valid - `w.date_stamp_utc between  '1-dec-2014' and '31-dec-2015'` You must use `to_date` if you want compare a dates...

Comment: yes, but this is not a issue.

Comment: @Tatiana In those cases Oracle will do an implicit `TO_DATE` on non-date literals using the value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the format mask. If the non-date literal matches this format then it will work - however, if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is ever changed then it will immediately break (any be a huge pain to debug as the code that was working won't but no-one will have changed the code). As you state it is better to use `TO_DATE` with the correct format mask or to use an ANSI date literal (i.e. `DATE '2014-12-01'`).

Comment: `w.date_stamp_utc between DATE '2014-12-01' and DATE '2015-12-31'` will pick up all dates and times inclusive of `2014-12-01 00:00:00` to `2015-12-31 00:00:00` and not up to `2015-12-31 23:59:59`. If the column has a time component and you are intending to get all the values for 2015 then you will miss almost all of those values for the last day. To solve this you can use `TRUNC(w.date_stamp_utc)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is caused by the field in your order by clause.  It is

```
order by waRating.attr_value desc, eform_name
```

In your select clause, you have this:

```
waEnv.attr_value environment
```

While the field name is the same, they are coming from different tables.  However, that probably doesn't matter because you also used an alias in your select clause.  Use the same one in your order by clause:

```
order by environment desc, eform_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` instead of `select distinct`:

```
select . . .
from . . .
where . . .
group by pi.first_name || ' ' || pi.last_name initiator
     , pi.user_id
     , c.country_name
     , e.eform_name
     , w.date_stamp_utc
     , decode(waRating.attr_value, 4, 'Very Positive',
                                   3, 'Positive',
                                   2, 'Neutral',
                                   1, 'Negative',
                                   0, 'Very Negative', '???')
     , waEnv.attr_value
     , nvl(ua.agent_name, '???')
     , nvl(ua.agent_version, '???')
     , waFeedback.attr_value 
order by waEnv.attr_value, eform_name;
```

Comment: Why would this make any difference?

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . The semantic rules on what is allowed for `select distinct` differs from `group by`.